# javascript mathematical formula editor?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Any open source javascript mathematical formula editor to recommend? I want to add mathematical formula editor to my web site, so that when people submit message using text box, they can insert related mathematical formula.

BTW: I am using VS 2010 + C# + .Net 4.0 + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0, any such controls provided by MSFT?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Tex style mathematical formular? Or clicky MS Word formular?

Comment: I just want to insert formula into text box. For example, inserting mathematical formula into "Ask Question" text box when we asking question in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This library surfaced recently: [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/)